# How exclude sunday from watson conversation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm newbie in coding and Watson Conversation and I'm trying to do a chatbot that schedule appointments from Monday to Saturday. I used @sys-date entity and it worked fine, but I don't know how to exclude sunday.For exemple:

*watson*: What is the best date for you?
*user*: sunday
*watson*: On this day the establishment is closed

I tried in the workspace: (condition) if: *action=='sunday'* like this: [workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/132de.png)

And coded like this in nodejs

```
    // Send the input to the conversation service

conversation.message(payload, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err)
  }else if(data.output.action==='sunday'){
    var date = new Date();
  if(!(date.getDay() % 6)){
    return res.json(payload,data.output.text["On this day the establishment is closed"]);
  }}else{
  return res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));
}});});
```

And it still gives me the sunday date(ex. 23/04/2017). I know that everything is wrong, but I really tried.. can somebody help me, please? I'd appreciate if you could put the code to help me..

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not a picture of your code. Read the FAQs on how to post code.

Comment: One thing I notice: `(payload, data.output.text["Sunday"])` is using the comma operator, and in this case that just ends up the same as `data.output.text["Sunday"]`. So what did you want to do here?

Comment: @trincot I tried to say: if user input sunday in the chat, the data.output.text would respond "On this day the establishment is closed" in the payload.. let me correct the code. tks!

Comment: I don't know the API, but `data.output.text["On this day the establishment is closed"]` looks wrong. You probably need `data.output.text = "On this day the establishment is closed";` as a separate statement, and then do `res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, yes... You can use the parameter `data` to send message with Watson and with user. And, you cant exclude "Sunday" from System entities. This entitie is only for help us with special Conditions.

In your case, use:

```
data.output.text[0] = "On this day the establishment is closed";
```

Because `data.output.text` send Watson message to Conversation.

But, one best practicie for a good *chatbot* is create `Intents` and `Entities` to pass **Intelligence** for your bot and retain as much intelligence as possible in your chatbot. And your app will only check.

For example, create one Entitie **@days** with values Sunday, monday, etc.

- Create one `intent` with examples how to ask "schedule appointments"
- Create one `Entitie` `@days` with values Sunday, monday, etc.
- Create one flow in your Dialog with Intent and Entitie condition (#bestDay and @days).

**And in your Advance JSON, add one context variable with day value like this:**

```
  {
  "context": {
    "day": "<? @days ?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Sorry. On $day the establishment is closed"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

**Check the flow:**

[image]

**Check the flow works fine:**

[image]

**If not sunday:**

[image]

Download the workspace to help you more [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzN1imYUZXryMlV0NHo5QmNEdkU).